# Paypal Tax Computation

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to edit the Paypal tax computation on my website. Right now, it's charging $5 on every order. I want to change it to 3% instead. So that 3% of the amount deposit will be charged on total. But I'm having trouble doing the code. Can someone please help me?

```
global $apiContext,$app_url;
$payer = new PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");
if(isset($_POST['random_amt'])){
    $price = $_POST['random_amt'] + 5;
}elseif(isset($_POST['sub_services'])){
    $price = get_service_price($_POST['sub_services']);
}else{
    $price = get_service_price($_POST['service_box']);
}
if($_FILES){

    $pics = count($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $price = $price*$pics;
```

Comment: This seems like very simple math to replace 5 with 3%. What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you guys! I've tried Mile's code and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$price = $_POST['random_amt'] + 5;
```

to

```
$int = $_POST['random_amt'] * .03;
$price = $_POST['random_amt'] + $int;
```

Comment: you saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @Miles. Can you help me with this one also? It's the same but Stripe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58966290/stripe-tax-computation?noredirect=1#comment104189756_58966290