# Stripe Tax Computation

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to edit the Stripe tax computation on my website. Right now, it's charging $5 on every order. I want to change it to 3% instead. So that 3% of the amount deposit will be charged on total. But I'm having trouble doing the code. Can someone please help me?

```
  if(isset($_POST['random_amt'])){
    $price = (double)$_POST['random_amt'].'' + (double)5;
    $name = main_services($_POST['service_box']);
  }elseif(isset($_POST['sub_services'])){

    $price = get_service_price($_POST['sub_services']);
    $name = service_box_arr($_POST['service_box'],$_POST['sub_services']);

  }else{
    $price = get_service_price($_POST['service_box']);
    $name = main_services($_POST['service_box']);
  }
```

Comment: your question is unclear.. plz describe it clearly

Comment: Hi @Aroon. I need it ot be 3% not $5. That's it.

Comment: Just like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58960810/paypal-tax-computation/58962575?noredirect=1#comment104184671_58962575

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the POST values directly. assign it to a variable

```
$amount = $_POST['random_amt'];
$serviceBox = $_POST['service_box'];
$subService = $_POST['sub_services'];

if(isset($amount)){
    $price = $amount * 1.03;
    $name = main_services($serviceBox);

  }elseif(isset($subService)){

    $price = get_service_price($subService);
    $name = service_box_arr($serviceBox,$subService);

  }else{
    $price = get_service_price($serviceBox);
    $name = main_services($serviceBox);
  }
```

Comment: 3% percent tax so the price should be `$price = $amount * 1.03;` you are just adding 3 cents to the price at the moment.